# Tensorflow Image Segmentation weights not updating

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm building a simple image segmentation network, based off the encoder/decoder architecture in TensorFlow and currently the model seems to run but it's not updating the weights. The inputs are my own dataset: images converted to numpy arrays of the shape `[-1,200,200,1]` with pixel-bu-pixel mask labels of shape `[-1,40000,3]`.

The code for my model function is here

```
def model(features, labels, mode):

    inpt = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1,200,200,1])

    #encoder
    x = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs = inpt,
        filters = 16,
        kernel_size = [2,2],
        padding = 'same',
        activation = tf.nn.relu)  
    x = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs = x, pool_size = [2,2], strides = 2)

    x = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs = x,
        filters = 32,
        kernel_size = [2,2],
        padding = 'same',
        activation = tf.nn.relu)
    x = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs = x, pool_size = [2,2], strides = 2)

    x = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs = x,
        filters = 64,
        kernel_size = [2,2],
        padding = 'same',
        activation = tf.nn.relu)
    x = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs = x, pool_size = [2,2], strides = 2)

    #decoder
    x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(x)
    x = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs = x,
        filters = 64,
        kernel_size = [2,2],
        padding = 'same',
        activation = tf.nn.relu)

    x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(x)
    x = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs = x,
        filters = 32,
        kernel_size = [2,2],
        padding = 'same',
        activation = tf.nn.relu)

    x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(x)   
    x = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs = x,
        filters = 16,
        kernel_size = [2,2],
        padding = 'same',
        activation = tf.nn.relu)

    x = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs = x,
        filters = 3,
        kernel_size = [1,1],
        padding = 'valid',
        activation = tf.nn.relu)

    logits = tf.reshape(x, [-1,3])

    predictions = {
        "classes": tf.argmax(input = logits, axis = 1),
        "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name = "softmax_tensor")
    }

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode = mode, predictions = predictions)

    labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1,3])

    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels = labels, logits = logits)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.0001)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(
            loss = loss,
            global_step = tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode = mode, loss = loss, train_op = train_op)


    eval_metric_ops = {
        "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
            labels = tf.argmax(labels, axis = 1), predictions = predictions["classes"])
    }
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode = mode, loss = loss, eval_metric_ops = eval_metric_ops)
```

I then call the model as follows:

```
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn = model, model_dir = '.')

tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
    tensors = tensors_to_log, every_n_iter = 50)

train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x = {"x": train},
    y = train_label,
    batch_size = 1,
    num_epochs = 5,
    shuffle = True)

classifier.train(
    input_fn = train_input_fn,
    steps = None)
```

The model is running but the accuracy score remains around the 35% mark and fails to train. If anyone has any suggestions they would be most appreciated.

Comment: I'd use `tf.layers.conv2d_transpose` instead of `tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D` in order not to mix Keras and Tensorflow layers.

Comment: My understanding is that they perform differently though. I'd like to use a nearest neighbours upsampling, which I believe Keras uses, as a transposed convolutional layer can add artefacts to the upsampled image which can confuse the output.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the question you say:

> the model seems to run but it's not updating the weights.

Then, at the end you say:

> the accuracy score remains around the 35% mark and fails to train

These are two different situations. In the first case, weights are not updated at all, while, in the second case, the are updated but their update  does not give any improvement in term of accuracy. You first need to check in which case you are.

#### CONSTANT WEIGHTS

If weights remain constant during training, you might be experimenting [gradient vanishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem). Your net has relu as activation function so it might be that almost all linear outputs (that is to say `Z = W*x + b`) are negative and the relu has gradient equal to 0 for negative inputs, so learning is not backpropagated through layers to each weight. You may try different activation function or, more common in CNN, add a Batch normalization layer after each conv layer.

#### CONSTANT ACCURACY

Thee are several causes.

1. Your network might be in a global optimum, hence it doesn't matter what you do, if you do not extend your dataset, you will not reach a better accuracy
2. Your network might be in a local optimum. Even if it is unlikely due to random initialization of weight, you should try implementing minibatch and/or shuffle your dataset at each iteration.
3. Your network is to simple and cannot understand the underlying relationship between inputs and outputs.
4. Your network is too complex. In this case, you should experiment overfitting if you leave your network training for an high number of epochs.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, @Neb, thanks for your answer. You're quite right, these are two distinct cases. I'll check which one it is. Regarding your answers to both cases though, I've implemented the same network in Keras and it performs well with the data I have so I thought there may be a syntactic error in my code.

Comment: Hi @JosephBullock. Note that you may experience slight different results using different frameworks (that's not the case here). If I helped you in anyway, could you please upvote me? Thanks!